# Delete all files while maintaining directory structure

Tags: batch-file, dos, delete-file

Given the directory structure c:\a\b\c\d\ - what DOS command will delete all files contained in c:\a along with any files in the subdirectories b, c, and d?  We do not want to delete any directories - just files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `DEL` command only deletes files, not directories, so the following command will do as you asked:

```
DEL /S C:\a
```

You need to use `RMDIR` to remove directories.

Comment: it keep on asking "are your sure" Y/N, can we avoid this message and directly delete files?

Comment: DEL /S /Q C:\a
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/del

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
del *.* /s /q
```

Check the directories are still there:

```
tree
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@del /S /Q /F a\* >nul
@for /d %%i in (a\*) do @rmdir /s /q "%%i"
```